# Android Emulator uses an old layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

Unfortunately I am developing an Android app using Android Studio (latest 1.0.2) on a Yosemite OS X computer.

The app includes a library created as an Android Library.

I modified a layout in the library using the visual editor of Android Studio. When I run the app the emulator keeps using the old layout.

I made the following attempts:

- cleaned the project
- rebuilt the project
- restarted Android Studio
- uninstalled the app from the running emulator
- rearranged items on the layout

No matter what I do, the emulator refuses to use the new layout.

Is there anyone who can help me?

The XML of the activity follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="it.misc.accountlib.RegisterNewUserActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/message_activity_register_new_user"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_text_size_large_material" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/nameAndSurnameTextField"
            android:hint="@string/name_surname" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/emailTextField"
            android:hint="@string/libaccount_email" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/nicknameTextField"
            android:hint="@string/libaccount_nickname"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/passwordTextField"
            android:password="false"
            android:hint="@string/libaccount_password" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_text_size_small_material" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/libaccount_register_new_account_button_text"
            android:id="@+id/registerNewUserButton" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then the app crashes in this method (called inside of `onCreate()` ):

```
protected void initUIElements() {
    nameSurnameTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameTextField);
    emailTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailTextField);
    nickNameTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nicknameTextField);
    passwordTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordTextField);
    registerNewUserButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerNewUserButton);

    // registerNewUserButton.setEnabled(false);

    registerNewUserButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerNewUserButton.setEnabled(false);
            verifyValuesAndRegister();
        } // onClick
    });
} // initUIElements
```

with this exception:

```
02-08 21:08:29.003    2666-2666/it.misc.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: it.misc.app, PID: 2666
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field emailTextField of type I in class Lit/misc/accountlib/R$id; or its superclasses (declaration of 'it.misc.accountlib.R$id' appears in /data/app/it.misc.app-1/base.apk)
        at it.misc.accountlib.RegisterNewUserActivity.initUIElements(RegisterNewUserActivity.java:38)
        at it.misc.accountlib.RegisterNewUserActivity.onCreate(RegisterNewUserActivity.java:29)
```

...

The only hint I have is this:

```
 /data/app/it.misc.app-1/base.apk
```

where it seems there are two `it.misc.app`  packages.

Comment: can you please share some code

Answer (score 0):

i know this is old, but I just had the same Issue and I solved it simply by reassining the View to another layout-xml with the same content, but a diffrent name.